# A way to know if the file currently is open before open it again?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a program which opens the same file several times.
I want to check before open any file if this file currently is open or not because I don't want to open the same file several times.

[image]

Is there a built-in function which can check if the file is currently open or any other way can do that?

**The Code:**

```
QString openFilePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this->mainWindow, "Open File");
if(openFilePath == ""){
    return;
}
QFile openFile(openFilePath);
if(!openFile.open(QFile::ReadWrite)){
    QMessageBox::critical(this->mainWindow, "Can't Open file", "Can't access to the file.");
}
QTextStream fileContent(&openFile);
QFileInfo fileInfo(openFile);
this->createEmptyFile(fileInfo.fileName());
this->txtEditor->setText(fileContent.readAll());
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, which Qt component you use, how you open a file etc.

Comment: @Slava: I have updated my question, you can now review my code.

Comment: Just maintain a list of opened files, remove it from there on close signal and check if it is not already there on open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that your question has really nothing to do with file opening in the programmatic sense, but is exclusively related to your application logic. You need to internally keep a list of all currently open files (in the sense that your GUI is showing such file), and do a check if the user opens a new file.

Comment: indeed. You anyway must to save the filenames which already opened

Answer (score 0):

Regular file open, say for append, depending on the function, will usually return NULL or raise an exception if the file is already open. There are stateless file systems where this approach may not work.

```
std::fstream fs;
try {
    fs.open("lk.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fs << "We're way beyond the boundaries of the Pride Lands.";
} catch (const std::ios_base::failure &ex) {
    // Something happened
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
fs.close();
```

In some file systems there are also shared open modes, which will explicitly let you concurrently reopen the file and do what you want with no errors generated.

Comment: "will usually return NULL or raise an exception if the file is already open" this behavior depends on OS.

Answer (score 0):

[existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841309/how-to-know-that-a-file-was-opened-qt)

also you can try the hack) I dont know would it works or not, but: in the

`void QFile::setFileName(const QString &name)`

function overview [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#setFileName) you can see that

> Do not call this function if the file has already been opened.

Hmm) what if try to rename it in `try catch` to avoid crashing and if the renaming done, rename it again and open?) so you can try.

Comment: Not sure but I would expect that the docs refer to that you should not call `setFileName` on a `QFile` instance that was opened before, but I dont think there will be any exception or problem if you use two distinct `QFile` instances to open the same file twice

Comment: @tobi303 I didn't tested it yet, but I can hear the logic in your words) Seems it is works as you say

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution to your problem:-

**is_open()**

*Scope*:
std::ofstream::is_open

1.it Check if file is open or not?

2.it returns whether the stream is currently associated to a file

3.it is public member function of **fstream**.

4.***parameters*** -none

**Sample Code:**

```
    #include <iostream>    
    #include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

    int main () 
    {
      std::ofstream ofs;
      ofs.open ("hye.txt");
      if (ofs.is_open())
      {
        ofs << "hellow world";
        cout << "successfully written to file";
        ofs.close();
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "Error opening file";
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

**output:**

successfully written to file

Comment: this works only if OP is using one and the same `ofsream` to open the same file twice, but I am pretty sure that OP is asking for opening the same file with two completely unrelated streams